# Apache multiple ProxyPass entries in one VirtualHost

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy

So I have the following two configurations:

On the one hand a backend server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName localhost
  ProxyPass /backend http://some_remote_ip:7000/backend
  ProxyPassReverse /backend http://some_remote_ip:7000/backend
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /backend
  ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain some_remote_ip localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

And on the other hand a frontend server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName localhost
  ProxyPass  /excluded !
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

If I put those in a `.conf` file together, only the one that is written first, in the file, will work, so technically they are both correct.

So my question is how can I have multiple `ProxyPass` entries ***in the same*** `VirtualHost` configuration?

P.S.: I need to be able to access

- the backend at `localhost/backend`
- the frontend at `localhost`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple VirtualHost sections for the same virtual host (`localhost`), so Apache will just pick one. If you want these configurations to work together, you have to put the `ProxyPass` directives in a single VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName localhost

  ProxyPass /backend http://some_remote_ip:7000/backend
  ProxyPassReverse /backend http://some_remote_ip:7000/backend
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /backend
  ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain some_remote_ip localhost

  ProxyPass  /excluded !
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Yes! I first tried to do it like that, but the reason it was not working, was because I needed to reverse the order - the backend needed to be first, because otherwise it was interfering with the routes of the frontend.